# How to do text processing in java

Tags: java, regex, csv, text-processing, opencsv

I have a csv file

```
 input.csv
    1,[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]
    2,[103.5,1.292],[103.9,1.4],[103.3,1.21]
    3,[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]
```

From this I need to convert it into

```
{

                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]]


                "properties": {
                    "id": "1"

                }
            },
            {

                "type": "LineString",
                "properties": {
                    "id": "2"

                },
                "coordinates": [[103.5,1.292],[103.9,1.4],[103.3,1.21]]



        },{

                "type": "LineString",
                "properties": {
                    "id": "3"

                },
                "coordinates": [[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]]



        }
```

I am now trying to do it in java.So I read the csv file with open csv

```
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String[] nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                for (String e: nextLine) {
                   // System.out.format("%s ", e);
                System.out.println( e.split(",",1));
                }
            }
```

But I am having problem while spliting the line.If you look at the first line then I  want to have 
`1`  as a part  and the rest  `[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]` as another part.So that I can build the String

```
  String s="{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": "+s[1]+"
     \"properties\": { \"id\":"+s[0]+"} }";
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Jens i do not read a json file I read a csv and write a JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
(\d+),(.*)
```

You don't need to split... if you execute it you get two group . Group 1 is the digit and Group 2 is the later contents
[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ELjthy/11)

Try this Sample:

```
final String regex = "(\\d+),(.*)";
final String string = "1,[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]\n"
     + "2,[103.5,1.292],[103.9,1.4],[103.3,1.21]\n"
     + "3,[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Is this the parameter to split `spilit.("(\d+),(.*)")`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONSimple to create the JSON you need. IN my opinion the simplest JSON lib. See this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the lines yourself:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    String nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int ix = nextLine.indexOf(',');
        if (ix >= 0) {
            String head = nextLine.substring(0, ix);
            String tail = nextLine.substring(ix+1);
            doSomethingWith(head, tail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot invoke indexOf(char) on the array type String[]` error throws for this

Comment: @Josh it's a String, not a String[]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that to get the data the way you need to have whatever is generating the input.csv file to encapsulate the different sections in quotes.

So either

```
input.csv
   1,"[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]"
   2,"[103.5,1.292],[103.9,1.4],[103.3,1.21]"
   3,"[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]"
```

Or

```
input.csv
   "1","[103.85,1.28992],[103.89,1.294],[103.83,1.216]"
   "2","[103.5,1.292],[103.9,1.4],[103.3,1.21]"
   "3","[103.6,1.291],[103.6,1.39],[103.3,1.29]"
```

Because as it is between the one and the end of the line there are six commas which any csv parser will interpret that the line has seven columns instead of two.